# Does Cytoscape.js have capability to add image to a node?

Tags: jquery, node.js, icons

I was searching for a javascript component to able me draw network topology using JQuery and found Cytoscape.js. but it seems to be unable to assign an image to nodes. Does anybody have experience working with Cytoscape.js to help me. if there is another graph diagram JS components which has capability of assigning images/icons to nodes, please suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: OK. I found gojs.js component in which there is many fantastic diagram types. I found sufficient the "Shop Floor Monitor" sample for my case.